# ActiveMQ without client authentication. Is the Keystore needed on the client side?

Tags: ssl, activemq-classic, public-key-encryption

I am using ActiveMQ without client authentication. Do I need the keystore in the client side? I'm asking this question because according to the [documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-use-ssl.html) it seems that the keystore is needed on the client side. But if we are not doing client authentication, what is the use of such a keystore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't necessarily need a key store if you aren't doing client authentication but you still need the trust store as your client needs to know if it has connected to a trusted broker.